# How is the "evented-io" in node.js any different from the windows event model

Tags: .net, architecture, async, node.js

I'm wondering how the "evented-io" in node.js any different from the windows async IO model?

Is the callback from node.js executed on a thread, if not, where is it run?

I don't mean to question the productivity or awesomeness of node, but specifically to understand if the architectural design differs from what is commonly done in the windows space, say with WCF or ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js runs a single  thread. the thread runs the event loop, and when the async I/O has data available, the corresponding callback runs.

I can't speak to Windows async i/o model.

According to its website, "Node's goal is to provide an easy way to build scalable network programs.". I'd venture to guess that you could achieve that goal quicker with Node than if you were writing a native Windows service in C++.

Comment: So two concurrent IO callbacks? They block or run concurrently? If concurrently, how is that possible w/o more than 1 thread?

Comment: node vs C++ - of course, node is the obvious choice

Comment: The callbacks run serially, in whatever order node's event loop decides.